# How do I retrieve the filename of the current script in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to retrieve the filename of the currently running script in AutoHotkey and save it to a variable.

For example, if my script were named `sample-script.ahk`, I would like to display a message saying "*The current script is sample-script.ahk*".

**How do I retrieve the filename of the currently active script in AutoHotkey?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `A_ScriptName` The filename of the current script, without its path, e.g. MyScript.ahk.

```
MsgBox, The current script is %A_ScriptName%
```

See: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#BuiltIn

and more particularly, https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ScriptName